# I'd like to have a Google Docs script automatically load?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I have a script that automatically updates a date in the header of a google document upon open. I'd like to not have to install this script individually for each document. I can create a template, but then everytime I create a new document, I have to go to New > Google Docs > From a template, and then select my template. I'd like to just click New > Google Docs, and have this template automatically load.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a dialog like this:

Code:

```
function onOpen(){
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('My Menu')
  .addItem("Open Templated Google Doc", 'showMyDialog')
  .addToUi()
}

function createTemplatedGoogleDoc(name){
  var doc=DocumentApp.create(name);
  doc.addHeader().appendParagraph(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "E MMM dd, yyyy"))
  //doc.getBody().appendParagraph(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "E MMM dd, yyyy"));
  //doc.getBody().getChild(0).removeFromParent();
  doc.saveAndClose()
  return doc.getUrl();
}

function showMyDialog(){
  var ui=HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('docwithdate');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(ui, 'My Doc with Date');
}
```

docwithdate.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  </head>
  <script>
    function createFile(){
      var name=document.getElementById('filename').value;
      google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(function(url){
        var html='<a href="'+ url +'">Go To File</a>';
        $(html).appendTo("body");
      })
      . createTemplatedGoogleDoc(name);
    }
  </script>
  <body>
    <input type="text" id="filename" />
    <input type="button" value="Create File" onClick="createFile()" />
  </body>
</html>
```

The dialog looks like this:

[image]

You type in the filename and click the button.  The script returns a link to your new file.

This gets rid of the dialog also:

```
function onOpen(){
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('My Menu')
  .addItem("Open Templated Google Doc", 'showMyDialog')
  .addToUi()
}

function createTemplatedGoogleDoc(name){
  var doc=DocumentApp.create(name);
  doc.addHeader().appendParagraph(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "E MMM dd, yyyy"))
  //doc.getBody().appendParagraph(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "E MMM dd, yyyy"));
  //doc.getBody().getChild(0).removeFromParent();
  doc.saveAndClose()
  var rObj={url:doc.getUrl(),filename:doc.getName()}
  return rObj;
}

function showMyDialog(){
  var ui=HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('docwithdate');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(ui, 'My Doc with Date');
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  </head>
  <script>
    function createFile(){
      var name=document.getElementById('filename').value;
      google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(function(rObj){
        var html='<br /><a href="'+ rObj.url +'" onClick="google.script.host.close();">Go To File:' + rObj.filename + '</a>';
        $(html).appendTo("body");
      })
      . createTemplatedGoogleDoc(name);
    }
  </script>
  <body>
    <input type="text" id="filename" />
    <input type="button" value="Create File" onClick="createFile()" />
  </body>
</html>
```

I would probably make it a webapp and put it in a bookmark for easy access.
So you'll just have to add this:

```
function doGet(){
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('docwithdate');
}
```

and deploy it.

> > I assume that you can add the template to this simple script.